# utf8 ---> cp866

Tags: c#, кодировка

Как сохранить string в файл перекодировав её в cp866.

Comment: UTF8 вы  откуда взяли? string в юникоде, но не в UTF8. UTF8 - одно-байтовая кодировка. А так VladD уже ответил.

Comment: кто вам сказал что utf-8 это однобайтовая кодировка? UTF-8 (от англ. Unicode Transformation Format, 8-bit — «формат преобразования Юникода, 8-битный») — одна из общепринятых и стандартизированных кодировок текста, которая позволяет хранить символы Юникода используя переменное количество байт (от 1 до 6).

Comment: @maint посмотрел RFC 3629, да, был не прав по поводу UTF-8. Но всего остального это не отменяет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас уже есть строка, попробуйте

```
File.WriteAllText(s, path, Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
```

---

Уточнение из комментария: если нужно перекодировать файл из 866 в utf-8, делайте так:

```
var text = File.ReadAllText(path1, Encoding.GetEncoding(866));
File.WriteAllText(text, path2, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Это сработает, если файл не *очень* большой (помещается в память программы), то есть, меньше пары гигабайт на x86-системах.

Comment: извините что надоедаю, но как мне наоборот из 866 в UTF8. Я просто хочу чтобы исходник asm файла который на utf8 переделывался на 866 кодировку, чтобы поддерживались русские буквы. Если всё делать вручную, то сначала из исходника я вырезаю все русские буквы, символы и прогоняю файл через NotePad++ в 866, затем я вставляю обратно все русские буквы и опять сохраняю, но как этот процесс реализовать в моей программе? :*(

Comment: @AlexRudenkiy: Дописал ответ.